# Can I set 2 tasks to share the same build status in CruiseControl.NET?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, cruisecontrol

I have 2 tasks in my CruiseControl settings that work on the same build:

- Build MyProg
- Rebuild MyProg

It's a C++ thing, occaisionally a rebuild (clean and build) is needed to clean up linking errors.

I would like the 2 tasks to share the same status (Failed/Succeeded). That way I'm not forced to re-run the Rebuild task just because it failed last time if I want to get everything back to "Green".

Anyone know how it can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of thought, I think I am going about this ass-backwards.

The "Rebuild" task could be replaced with a very minimal "Clean" task which should pass whether the build is broken or not. The "Build" task would then automatically trigger following the "Clean", updating the official build result.